# Why can't create numeric $_SESSION key?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Please let me know can I create numeric `$_SESSION` key or not?

Like `$_SESSION[1];`

If you can, are there any rules or limitations?

If you can't, why is it not possible?

Comment: I'm real sorry to say, but you're asking before testing something quick like this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can.
None.
You should try experimenting on it.